# Check values existence using spss syntax

Tags: spss

I should check existence of values based on some conditions.

i.e. i have 3 variables, varA, varB and varC. varC should not be empty only if varA>varB (condition).

i normally use some syntax to check any of the variables and run a frequency of any of them to see if there are errors:

```
if missing(varC) and (varA>varB) ck_varC=1.
if not(missing(varC)) and not(varA>varB) ck_varC=2.
exe.
fre ck_varC.
exe.
```

I had some errors when the condition became complex and when in the condition there are missing() or other functions but i could have made a mistake.

do you think there is an easier way of doing this checks?

thanks in advance

EDIT: here an example of what i mean, think at a questionnaire with some routing, you ask age to anyone, if they are between 17 and 44 ask them if they work, if they work ask them how many hours.

[image: Example]

i have an excel tool where i put down all variables with all conditions, then it will generate the syntax in the example, all with the same structure for all variables, considering both situations, we have a value that shouldn't be there or we don't have a value that should be there.

is there an easier way of doing that?   is this structure always valid no matter what is the condition?

Comment: It is not fully clear what you want to achieve. Indeed, is varA or varB are missing, the ">" condition becomes... messy :D. I guess your `ck_varC` variable was still empty. Those are separate scenarios; in SPSS, missing values are not numbers. You need to explicitly program those scenarios as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SPSS, missing values are not numbers. You need to explicitly program those scenarios as well. you got `varC` covered (partially), but no scenario where `varA` or `varB` have missing data is covered.

(As good practice, *maybe* you should initialize your check variable as sysmis or 0, using syntax):

```
numeric ck_varC (f1.0).
compute ck_varC=0.
if missing(varC) and (varA>varB) ck_varC=1.
if not(missing(varC)) and not(varA>varB) ck_varC=2.
***additional conditional scenarios go here:.
if missing(varA) or missing(varB) ck_varC=3.
...
fre ck_varC.
```

By the way - you do not need any of the `exe.` commands if you are going to run your syntax as a whole.

**Later Edit, after the poster updated the question:**

Your syntax would be something like this. Note the use of the `range` function, which is not mandatory, but might be useful for you in the future.
I am also assuming that `work` is a string variable, so its values need to be referenced using quotation signs.

```
if missing(age) ck_age=1.
if missing(work) and range(age,17,44) ck_work=1.
if missing(hours) and work="yes" ck_hours=1.
if not (missing (age)) and not(1>0) ck_age=2. /*this will never happen because of the not(1>0).
if not(missing(work)) and (not range(age,17,44)) ck_work=2. /*note that if age is missing, this ck_work won't be set here.
if not(missing(hours)) and (not(work="yes")) ck_hours=2.
EXECUTE.
```

String variables are case sensitive
There is no `missing` equivalent in strings; an empty blank string ("") is still a string. `not(work="yes")` is `True` when `work` is blank ("").

Comment: Sorry, i didn't explain properly,  i normally do that for all variables, i this case if varA and varB should always be there i would also have

    if (1>0) and missing(VarA) ck_varA=1.
    if not(1>0) and not(missing(VarA)) ck_varA=2.
    .... 
    fre varA to varC.
    exe.

If all the variables involved in the condition are correct, is the structure correct, no matter the complexity of condition?

Comment: 1>0 means that it need always to be not missing ((1>0) and missing(VarA) ck_varA=1 is true when varA is missing). I used this because i need to check a lot of variables with a lot of conditions, i have created an excel file wich creates the syntax for all the variables at once

Comment: ok, I got the purpose of `1>0`, silly me :D. But `not(1>0)` is always false, so anything you build using this and the `and` operator will always be false...

Comment: that row is not necessary, it's just an example as it is part of an automatism. i create code for both the conditions for all the variables. i was talking in general. my question was about how i built this check:   if missing(something) and (condition) ck=1    ------ or the negation of both terms  ------- if not(missing(something)) and not(condition) ck=2.     is that always true regardless all the functions i can use in the condition??? sorry for my confused explanation. can i attach an excel file or some other files as example??

Comment: then you would have `missing` in `ck` when: (1) `missing(something) and not(condition)` and (2) `not (missing(something)) and (condition)`.

Comment: are you actually trying to reduce the whole thing to a binary (true/false) statement...? somethign which is either true or false, and never results in a missing...?

Comment: @corky81 you can edit your original post to add an example from your excel sheet, and to clarify your question

Comment: @horace_vr the missing value in ck means that the value is correct. is this structure correct in any case? obviously if all the previous values are correct - in the example for the ID=1 ck_work will be missing as age is missing, but that's fine because i need to update age an run the syntax again, and once i filled age ck_work will be ok

Comment: @corky81 I edited my answer based on your input; see if it works for you